# How to insert text in tkinter GUI while code is running

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Hi I am try to create an Python GUI using tkinter package. Everything working perfectly but I want to insert or print some text while code is running. My code is little length process, I did not include all the code, to execute i need some update information on the Text area, so that user know coding is running and getting some information from internet.

Could you please kindly check this code. In this code number will insert in the Tkinter GUI and will be increase continuously. But i want to inset text form the given list. How can I insert text form the list. Please kindly help.

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import queue
from time import sleep
import random
import tkinter as tk

list1 = ['Text 1', 'Text 2','Text 3','Text 4','Text 5','Text 6','Text 7',
         'Text 8','Text 9','Text 10','Text 11']

class Thread_0(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        count = 0
        while True:
            count+=1
            hmi.thread_0_update(count)
            sleep(random.random()/100)

class HMI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.master= tk.Tk()
        self.master.geometry('200x200+1+1')

        f=tk.Frame(self.master)
        f.pack()

        self.l0=tk.Label(f)
        self.l0.pack()

        self.q0=queue.Queue()

        self.master.bind("<<Thread_0_Label_Update>>",self.thread_0_update_e)

    def start(self):
        self.master.mainloop()
        self.master.destroy()

    def thread_0_update(self,val):
        self.q0.put(val)
        self.master.event_generate('<<Thread_0_Label_Update>>',when='tail')


    def thread_0_update_e(self,e):
        while self.q0.qsize():
            try:
                val=self.q0.get()
                self.l0.config(text=str(val))
#                self.l0.config(text=val)
            except queue.Empty:
                pass

##########################
if __name__=='__main__':
    hmi=HMI()
    t0=Thread_0()
    t0.start()
    hmi.start()
```

Comment: One solution would be to open a new Thread for getting information from internet and an another for the Gui.

Comment: You've posted a _lot_ of what appears to be irrelevant code. Please try to reduce it down to a [mcve]. Also, please fix the indentation.

Comment: you have to run process in separated `thread` and probalby use `queue` to send results/information to main thread. Main thread can use `root.after()` to execute function (every few seconds) which will get data from queue and put in GUI.

Comment: Please kindly check the code. I edit some part.